# DIY BLDC - power supply sizing?

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, diy

I am currently in the process of building a sensor-less 3ph axial flux BLDC with concentrated windings. I’m thinking 12s10p but have not yet decided. It’s just for a project - not for real world applications. And by no means and I am expert in this subject. However I am trying to gauge what size power supply I will need to drive it. I know that the speed I want it to operate at will also impact this to some degree. However is their a rule of thumb which will help take this into consideration. If I know the parameters of 1/12 of the coils.

Below are the estimated results I get when using a solenoid calculator for one coil. (They are air coils)

Coil Parameters |
Wire Diameter -     .321 (mm)
Number of Turns - 2000 (turns)
Bobbin Length - 40 (mm)
Bobbin Diameter - 31 (mm)
Rated Current  -  1amp (I)
Gap Distance -  1 (mm)
Results

Turns per Layer - 124 (Turns per Layer)
Number of Layers - 16 (Layers)
Coil Diameter - 40 (mm)
Cross Section Area - 970 (mm²)
Total Length of Wire - 220 (M)
Total weight of wire - .159 ( Kg)
Resistance/(M) - .213 (Ohm/M)
Resistance - 47.063 (ohms)
Inductance  - 88549 (uH)
Voltage at Rated Current - 47.063 (V)
Power at Rated Current  - 47.063 (W)
Electromagnetic Force   - 1776 (N) 399 (Lbs)
Cross Section Area - 706  (mm²) (A)

Comment: BLDC is an adjective, you are building a BLDC *what*?

Comment: _”Power at Rated Current - 47.063 (W)”_ So at least 47 W + your drivers losses.

Comment: If the coil resistance is 47R and the supply is 47V then the STALL current (per coil) is only 1A; the motor operating current will be MUCH smaller once you  allow for the back EMF ... this will be a pretty low power motor.